# How to get element assoicated to onClick event

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm very new to Dart, and I'm encountering a problem with this code:

```dart
DivElement badge = querySelector('.badge');
badge.onClick.listen(onBadgeClick);
```

The event handler looks like this:

```dart
void onBadgeClick(MouseEvent e){
    print(e.relatedTarget);
}
```

I get this exception

> Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot call matchingTarget if this
>   Event did not arise as a result of event delegation.

How can I get the element that the click is associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` should you give the element that created the event. If you set a breakpoint in DartEditor the code execution halts on the line with the breakpoint and you can investigate the properties of the `e` instance.